# SDWebImage not returning correct image UICollectionView for first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I have a `SDWebImage` version 3.7.3, in which I am using  `sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:options:completed:`

Whenever I am trying to load from the collectionview for the first time while the actual image is getting downloaded, it is displaying the image of some other cells image. After the download is complete its working fine. Any ways to fix this and show the placeholder image.

I have tried several solutions `sd_cancelimagerequest` in `prepareForReuse` and setting the `imageview.image = nil` and setting in on the main thread but none of them seems working.

Answer (score 2):

In your `- collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, set your `UIImage` to nil in your cell before calling `sd_setImageWithURL:`.

Chances are, the `collectionView` is re-using the old cell to minimize the performance hit.

Comment: I have did the same but still i have some image loading wrong issue, sometimes after the proper image is set another image is setting.

Answer (score 0):

reset the image of imageView to nil in `- collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

if you set the image of imageView in completed closure `(^SDWebImageCompletionBlock)(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)`, you should check if the imageURL parameter is equal to the real url that cell needs

Comment: Any solution here @raghul? I am experiencing the same issue for UIImageView's inside collection view cells that don't update (when others around them do). They end up getting other cells images..